# Solving the SIGKILL killing signal

Tags: sigkill

I'm trying to run a simulation on my local computer in university, but after some iterations it's being killed by a SIGKILL. Even when I check the available swap space it shows that still I have enough space !!!

```
:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3937       2091       1845          0         64        677
-/+ buffers/cache:       1349       2587
Swap:         3860        738       3122
```

The same story repeats when I use another server by ssh

```
:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        129043      98281      30761         52          4      32901
-/+ buffers/cache:      65375      63668
Swap:         4095        120       3975
```

When I run it on my own laptop it works properly.
I'd really appreciate if help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the swap space after the fact or during the run? If there is a memory crunch the operating system's out of memory killer (OOM Killer) may kill the process ( depending on the configuration this could be the worst offender, random or anything else). Execute "sar" command and see the system state around the time your process got killed.